# Removing ambiguous lines from csv using Pandas or csv python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, python-3.5

I have tried to remove the duplicate from the line using the following code:

```
import csv

file_in = '1.csv'
file_out = 'output_file.csv'
with open(file_in, 'r',encoding="utf-16") as fin, open(file_out, 'w',encoding="utf-16") as fout:
    reader = csv.reader(fin)
    writer = csv.writer(fout)
    d = {}
    for row in reader:
        color = row[0]
        if color not in d:
            d[color] = row  
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Here is the output file of my above program: [File Output](https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/ff07446dbfc5c3cf37023a3bbdd93bc4)
Here is the input file: [File Input](https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/9967d711362b275e3486e32536bd2686)

But there is a problem I thought I will get the filtered values, but the logic only remove the copied lines. See the following result values:

**For the same values I am getting yes as well as no in the different rows. These are ambiguous values**

```
1   0   -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  yes
1   0   -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  no
1   0   1   1   1   -1  -1  -1  yes
1   0   1   1   1   -1  -1  -1  no
```

These are ambiguous values and have nothing impact on my neural model. These are creating ambiguous situations.

I am willing to remove such entries along with the duplicate rows. I was willing to use pandas, but don't have much knowledge. Kindly, help me remove the duplicate rows from the csv along with the ambiguous values.

Mostly all the values are same except the last column which may have different values.

Comment: what defines an "ambiguous value" ?

Comment: I have already mentioned it in the question. PLease check the question

Comment: No, you have posted some values saying the were "ambiguous" but you have not explained why you consider them as such.

Comment: ok. The reason is, while I am trying to feed it to my system of script where I am using it for decision making, such values are making false predictions, which is not good. I want to eliminate such rows as well. From my dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the very handy function of `pandas` to remove the duplicates. Say that your csv file is called `file.csv`. Then you can load your data into a dataframe called `df` and you want to remove duplicates excluding the last column.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')    
drop_cols = df.columns[:-1]
df.drop_duplicates(subset=drop_cols, inplace=True)
```

**EDIT**

In case your csv file doesn't have headers replace `pd.read_csv('file.csv')` with

```
pd.read_csv('file.csv', header=None)
```

Comment: Not working .. I am getting the error and this is not the answer I am expecting:`ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)`

Comment: Can you give me some more details of where the error is thrown? At which line?
And something more, this assumes that your csv file has headers.